# "Migrate" database with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, database-migration

I have a program using NHibernate, recently we have made an update to the database model, we have added a table. Now we use SQLite to sync parts of the "central" database to enable a offline support in the program. It is now the problems start arising... When a user have an updated version of the program, but an old version of the database NHibernate wont work properly.

So I would like to "migrate" the database to the new schema. I have testet with `SchemaExport`, but that clears the database of all it's data. Do I have to manually create the table?

Also, I only notice this when I try to access a lacy loaded property in my database, is there anyway to see if the model correlates with the database schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SchemaUpdate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html#SchemaUpdate(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration)) instead.

It will check your current schema with mapping files. If any changes in mapping files (table added as you said) will be reflected to underlying RDBMS. A DDL will be automatically generated by NHibernate and will be executed to match the changes.

Sample code is something like below:

```
SchemaUpdate schemaUpdate = new SchemaUpdate(configuration);
schemaUpdate.Execute(false, true);
```

Depending on your need, you may play with two parameters of [`Execute`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html#execute(boolean,%20boolean)) -- self explanatory.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to do it for just one table? (I tried `config.AddAssembly(typeof(MyTableModel).Assembly)` but that seems to take the full model and not just the MyTableModel table).

Comment: AFAIK, it is intended to work on all models. Actually, it should automatically find out the differences. To do that, it must scan all the models.